# zend framework 2 controller factory conditional loading

Tags: php, zend-framework2, lazy-loading

I am searching for a proper way of handling creation of a controller via factory (to avoid strict dependencies to services in controller itself to allow unit testing).

I have a controller with 2 actions:

1. search form submission in which I only use Zend Form with validators
   to determine if a valid query was send to it and, if it was,
   redirect to show results action
2. show results - I use https://github.com/ripaclub/sphinxsearch to
   talk to Sphinx Search

Now, my factory for creation of controller looks like that:

```
$ctrl = new Album\Controller\SearchController();
$ctrl->setSearchForm(new Album\Form\SearchForm());
$ctrl->setSearchEntity(new Album\Model\Search());
$sphinxqlAdapter = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('SphinxSearch\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$ctrl->setSphinxqlAdapter($sphinxqlAdapter);
$ctrl->setSphinxqlMatch($serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('sphinxqlMatch'));
$ctrl->setSphinxqlSearch($serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('SphinxQlSearchFactory'));
return $ctrl;
```

The thing is, that even my first action (which is simple form validation + redirect) gets all classes for Sphinx injected and ready to use... but they are useless there. I tried to use Lazy Services as stated here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.service-manager.lazy-services.html and it works for my 'sphinxqlMatch' service - this class does not get instantiated when calling form action. The problem is with SphinxSearch\Db\Adapter\Adapter because it uses a factory to create a database adapter for running SphinxQL services. While I get no exceptions, I checked that adapter gets instantiated immediately so no proxy'ing occurs.

Anybody has experience with lazy services and how to make it work with factories? Or maybe some other pattern is better here - please provide hints/solutions.

I know I could alternatively divide those two actions into separate controllers as the final resort, but for me it makes sense that search form submission routines and displaying search results logically fits together :)

Comment: Did you tried to override the `SphinxSearch\Db\Adapter\Adapter` service with your own lazy config ? If yes, can you add the configuration to your question ?